# Filtering JSON in php by greater than current date

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to filter the json response by date greater than today

My JSON look like is:

```
{
    "responseData": [
        {
            "totalValue": 0.0,
            "active": "Oct 16, 2019 11:16:23 AM",
            "expired": "Mar 28, 2020 3:15:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "totalValue": 0.0,
            "active": "Oct 16, 2019 11:16:23 AM",
            "expired": "Mar 28, 2020 3:15:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "totalValue": 0,
            "active": "Jun 25, 2019 6:34:59 PM",
            "expired": "Oct 16, 2019 11:10:32 AM",
    }
    ],
    "responseMessage": "success",
    "responseCode": 0
}
```

and the php script to filter:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');


$date1 = date('M d, Y H:i:s A'); //Oct 16, 2019 11:16:23 AM

    $json = json_decode($mybalance, true);
    usort($json['responseObject'], function($date1, $b) { return $date1 > $b['expired']; } );
    $mybalance2 = json_encode($json);

    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

    echo $mybalance2;
```

But the output still display all data instead of filtering, my expected output is:

```
{
    "responseData": [
        {
            "totalValue": 0.0,
            "active": "Oct 16, 2019 11:16:23 AM",
            "expired": "Mar 28, 2020 3:15:58 PM"
        },
        {
            "totalValue": 0.0,
            "active": "Oct 16, 2019 11:16:23 AM",
            "expired": "Mar 28, 2020 3:15:58 PM"
        }
    ],
    "responseMessage": "success",
    "responseCode": 0
}
```

Has tried finding the solutions over google but not working :(

Comment: from where you get `$b['toDate']`?. Also `$date1 = date('M d, Y H:i:s A');` will give you current date

Comment: Hi @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie, sorry that's type it should be `$b['expired'];` yes I want to grab current date as comparison, my goal is only to show data if greater than current date, so if the expired data will not showing in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually filtering data, as `usort()`  will Sort array by values using a user-defined comparison function.(what you defined already)

Do:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$date1 = 'Oct 16, 2019 11:16:23 AM';

$json = json_decode($mybalance, true);

foreach($json['responseData'] as $key=>$value){

    if(strtotime($value['expired']) < strtotime(date('M d, Y H:i:s A'))){

        unset($json['responseData'][$key]);

    }
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/AAqgJ

Note:- you can use `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` instead of `strtotime(date('M d, Y H:i:s A'))`.

Sample output : https://3v4l.org/Ba7H9